# UILongPressGesture gets called twice

Tags: swift, uilongpressgesturerecogni

So when ever I long press on a button, it recognizes the long press, but "test" gets called twice. How do I prevent that from happening?

```
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

func longPressMe(){
   print("test")
}

func longPressGes(){
    let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressMe")
    longpress.minimumPressDuration = 1
    button2.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    longPressGes()
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a try, here is how to use #selector:

```
func longPressMe(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
   // do stuff here
}

func longPressGes(){
    let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(yourViewController.longPressMe(_:)))
    longpress.minimumPressDuration = 1
    button2.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton. i appreciate it. couldn't get it for awhile.

Answer (score 3):

You have to check the state of the gesture recognizer. Change `longPressMe()` to something like this:

```
func longPressMe(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard recognizer.state == .Began else { return }

    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: with bot my way and your way i  keep getting *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[testtest.ViewController pressAction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: You can't use a string for a selector anymore. Use the new `#selector` syntax instead.

Comment: @DAMONGONZALEZ change selector to `#selector(longPressMe(_:))` or if it is an old version of Xcode/Swift use `action: "longPressMe:"`